# Jetpack Compose Canvas not drawing text with correct style

Tags: android, canvas, android-jetpack-compose

I am drawing a text into a canvas using the following code snippet :-

```
drawText(
    textMeasurer = textMeasurer,
    text = it.text,
    topLeft = it.start,
    style = currentStyle.value!!
)
println("Custom canvas: Current textFont is ${currentStyle.value!!}.........................")
```

This gives an output of

```
Custom canvas: Current textFont is TextStyle(color=Color(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, sRGB IEC61966-2.1), brush=null, alpha=1.0, fontSize=12.0.sp, fontWeight=null, fontStyle=Normal, fontSynthesis=null, fontFamily=FontFamily.Default, fontFeatureSettings=null, letterSpacing=Unspecified, baselineShift=null, textGeometricTransform=null, localeList=null, background=Color(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, None), textDecoration=TextDecoration.Underline, shadow=null, drawStyle=null, textAlign=null, textDirection=null, lineHeight=Unspecified, textIndent=null, platformStyle=null, lineHeightStyle=null, lineBreak=null, hyphens=null, textMotion=null).........................
```

Note that the output contains `textDecoration=TextDecoration.Underline` yet the text that is being displayed does not have any underline.
If the printed value of currentStyle.value contains an underline, shouldn't the drawn text also have an underline?
Also I have a lot of other code which I have omitted for simplicity, if needed I will provide those

Comment: are you getting expected result when you run `drawText( textDecoration = TextDecoration.Underline)` instead of `style=`?

Comment: @Dilshad I am getting a Compiler error:
`None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.`

Comment: @Dilshad I just tested after replacing TextMeasurer with TextLayoutResult and adding the textDecoration parameter as you suggested and now it works as intended. Can you please tell me why replacing TextMeasurer with TextLayoutResult works?

Comment: There are different variants of the same function, each taking arguments in a different way. When you pass two arguments containing values that are supposed to be taken by the same variant of a function but instead you add values of arguments for different variants(probably caused by some mistake in importing packages), the IDE will successfully understand what you are trying to do, but you may not get the expected result.

(I am not 100% sure if this is what happened from the details available therefore i think i shouldnt be posting this as an answer)